# Bad Request (400) when trying to submit data

Tags: jquery, flask

I'm having some strange issues regarding the Bad Request error. Here is my flask code to handle the POST request

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    tablename = request.form["jukename"]
    videoURL = request.form["url"]
    videoTitle = request.form["videoTitle"]
    videoDuration = request.form["videoDuration"]
    vlocation = request.form["location"]
    vcursor = request.form["cursor"]

    add_video(tablename, videoURL, videoTitle, videoDuration, vlocation, vcursor)
    return jsonify(result={"status": 200})
```

And here is my Jquery code that makes the request:

```
    $('#results').on("click",'.search-list',function(){
    var juke = $("#jukename").text();
    var url = $(this).attr("video-id");
    var vtitle = $(this).attr("video-title");
    var vduration = $(this).attr("video-duration");
    var vcursor = cursor;
    var vlocation = 0;

    $.post("/add",{jukename: juke,url: url, videoTitle: vtitle, videoDuration: vduration, location:vlocation, cursor: vcursor},function(data){});
    getPlaylist();
});
```

'results' is an ul element that gets populated from an API. The relevant data is passed as arguments in the search-list class.

I know that this kind of error is caused when a input field's name is different than the arguments in the add(). 
However I'm using the same script.js in two different pages. The HTML are very similar. Page1 has a few more elements than Page2 needs, so it's basically a Copy-Paste from the Page1 with some things removed (nothing related to the 'results').
In Page1, this works fine, but I get this error when I try use it in Page2. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found out. I deleted a function that defined the cursor variable. Just defined elsewhere and everything worked fine